# Is the product of simply connected algebraic groups simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

A connected group variety is simply connected if every multiplicative isogeny from a connected group variety to it is an isomorphism. (Taken from p.388 of Milne's book on algebraic groups) I would imagine that the answer is yes, but don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

For semisimple groups the answer is yes. This can be seen from the fact that they are the semisimple groups whose character group is the weight lattice.